# Infinitely looped path when trying to copy output files

Tags: linux, mpi, cp

I'm trying to run a simulation on a linux cluster. On the head node in my home directory I have

```
/home/checkouts (contains the executable of the model)
```

and

```
/home/models/run (contains the input files for the model)
```

During the simulation I save output data on a local node and at the end I want to copy the output files to /home/models/output/run. What I get is an infinite loop of ouput/run/run folders like this

```
/home/models/output/run/run/output/run/run/output/run/run/output/run/run ...
```

Does someone have an idea where I made a mistake? I use the following sh script to run the model:

```
rundir=$PWD

outputdir=/home/models/output

run=$(basename $rundir)         # run

cp -r $rundir /var/tmp/$run
pushd /var/tmp/$run

mpirun -np $NO_OF_CORES -machinefile nodes ~/checkouts/x_model-v1.21.$

popd
cp -r /var/tmp/$run $outputdir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-P` option when copying symlinks or better yet use `-d`.:

> -P, --no-dereference    never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
>
> -d    same as --no-dereference --preserve=links
>
> --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]    preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all

This will help prevent going into infinte loops when encountering circular links. I also suggest quoting your variables properly to prevent word splitting and unexpected pathanme expansion.

```
cp -dr "$rundir" "/var/tmp/$run"
```

You can also consider `-a` over `-dr`.